# what is the WTED file and what is it used for?

Tags: debian, chkrootkit

What is the WTED file and what is it used for?

We ran the chkrootkit command and this was the output: 
`Checking 'wted'... 1 deletion(s) between <start date> and <end date>`

After a lot of googling unfortunately we got nothing that clearly tells us what it is or is used for, or what it may indicate.

Comment: chkrootkit is notorious for false positives. Post the exact output.

Comment: The rest was nothing special, it was just this that stood out

Comment: OK, then as you will not post the output , see http://www.chkrootkit.org/README , search the page for 'wted'

Comment: @xorinzor I'm seeing this, too. Were you ever able to figure out the cause of the deletion?

Comment: @pdoherty926 I'm afraid not. We just ended up reinstalling the server and implemented additional security measures (because we got, we think, hacked).